# GET Requests do not have responses - Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, angular-http

I'm using Angular2 to GET values from an endpoint with an Ionic 2 App.

The code in my `dashboard.service.ts` file:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Dashboard} from './pages/dashboard/dashboard';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {
  constructor(private http:Http) {

  }
  private _dashboardUrl = 'http://api.commutatus.com/api/trucks?api_token=XXXXX';

  getDashboards() {
    return this.http.get(this._dashboardUrl)
                    .map(res => <Dashboard[]> res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError (error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

From the console - I can see that the requests are going but they are marked as RED on the console but they seem to have 200OK response.

I have even tried with the url - http://google.com but have the same issue.

[image]

Comment: You need to fix the server so it does respond with the correct CORS headers.

Comment: You have cross-origin requests, so you have to configure your "Content Security Policy", I do not know how to do it for ang2 with ionic2 so it is just a tip. I assume you are trying to hit api.commutatus.com and your application is not running on this domain.